# Why do I get incorrect SUM in my MYSQL query joining two tables?

Tags: mysql

The simple working query, list the number of licenses for each license type:

Query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(licenses.licenseID) AS total
FROM
  licenses
GROUP BY
  licenses.licensetypeID
```

Results:

```
total
=====
389
 14
  2
  5
  3
  1
  1
```

Now I want to sum up the profit from the licenses. A table `transactions` contains all transactions from PayPal. I use `mc_gross` to sum up. Some times there are refunds, so `mc_gross` is negative and there are more transactions than licenses.

In my current database, four licenses was removed because the transaction was refunded.

My attempt:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(licenses.licenseID) AS total,
  SUM( transactions.mc_gross ) AS gross
FROM
  licenses
  LEFT JOIN transactions ON licenses.txn_id = transactions.txn_id
GROUP BY
  licenses.licensetypeID
```

The result:

```
393     9020.00
 14     NULL
  2     NULL
  5     NULL
  3     100.00
  1     NULL
  1     NULL
```

Notice that the first license type now has a total of four more than the first query. From this I deduce that it's counting up the extra rows in the transactions table. But I do not understand why, because I thought a `LEFT JOIN` would take all the rows for the left table `licenses` and connect to whatever available `transactions`.

Reading up on the different joins I cannot make any sense of them to produce my desired result.

Am I doing an incorrect join? Or do I group by the wrong value?

Note that I do want to list all license types - even if they sum up to zero count.

(Let me know if the whole table structure is required - I skipped it to avoid making the question too long. I hope all the relevant info is included.)

Comment: try count(distinct license.licenseid) to avoid counting duplidates

Comment: @Jason: That corrected my count. But now I see another problem. The total profit is wrong as well. But this is due to what @StilesCrisis mentions, there are duplicate `txn_id` some times because they payment has been pending. Looks like I need to filter out these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably multiple Transactions with the same `TXN_ID`. In that case, a join will list the same License once per each matching Transaction.

Comment: Ah, yes. Looking at the data. Some times a transaction is recorded, but it's pending processing. In these cases a second transaction with the same `txn_id` will occur. This is what throws it off.

Answer (score 0):

If refunds are entered in the transaction table as negative amounts, you shouldn't remove the original transaction.  Both need to be present to make the total balance to 0.  Since you're seeing 4 more transactions than you thought, and you know there were 4 refunds, I'd say both the original transaction and the refund transaction are in the transaction table, as they should be.

Comment: You are correct, it is not my refunds. It is duplicate `txn_id` entries because of occasional pending payments that cause duplicate transaction entries with the same `txn_id`. I saw that now based on @StilesCrisis' comment.

Comment: If I'm correct, but you have true duplicates rather than simply multiple transactions per license when refunded, then your non-distinct count would be greater than (license count + refund count).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I got I managed to create a query that produces correct results:

```
SELECT
  COUNT( distinct licenses.licenseID ) AS total,
  SUM( temp.mc_gross / temp.quantity ) AS gross
FROM
  licenses
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT txn_id, mc_gross, quantity
      FROM transactions
      WHERE valid = 'VERIFIED-PAID'
    ) AS temp ON licenses.txn_id = temp.txn_id
GROUP BY
  licenses.licensetypeID
```

Correct data:

```
total   gross
===================
389     7780.000000
 14     NULL
  2     NULL
  5     NULL
  3     60.000000
  1     NULL
  1     NULL
```

UPDATE - Improved query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT( licenses.licenseID ) AS total,
  SUM( transactions.mc_gross / transactions.quantity ) AS gross
FROM
  licenses
  LEFT JOIN transactions ON licenses.txn_id = transactions.txn_id AND transactions.valid = 'VERIFIED-PAID'
GROUP BY
  licenses.licensetypeID
```

Comment: You could have done the `valid = 'VERIFIED-PAID'` check in the `ON` clause of your `JOIN`, I think.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Yes! It does! Did not know you could do that. Much simpler and much easier to read. Thank you!